# Lion indicating wrong version of JDK installed

Tags: macos, java

I have just ran through the installer for JDK 1.7.0_05, downloaded from Oracle.com, but my Mac is still indicating that the preinstalled JDK 1.6.0_33 is installed:

```
MacBook-Air:~ $ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_33
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Java Preferences app in the Utilities folder and move "Java SE 7" to the top of the list.